# Insert module inserts image twice?

Tags: 7

So I'm kind of new to Drupal and I apologise if this is a stupid question. But I've been trying to get both [FlexSlider](http://drupal.org/project/flexslider) and [Insert](http://drupal.org/project/insert) to display correctly in the frontend. I've add them to the basic content content type.

Both modules have an image field and display associated with them and they do indeed show up in the frontend, but if I use the Insert module then the image gets show twice and I can't get FlexSlider to appear before the content.

The Edit screen displays correctly:

[image: Home page edit screen]

You can see the slider image field is before the body content and title as I've defined in fields and there is only one image upload and an insert button which works as expected.

But then if you look at what is output on the home page:

[image: Home page view]

You can see that (a) the slider is showing at the bottom of the page and (b) the uploading images are displayed unless I delete them after uploading and inserting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to go to the "Manage Display" admin page for your content type (e.g. http://mysite.com/admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields for the 'article' content type).

There you can hide/reorder all of the fields in your content type.

I would guess that currently you have a display field that's aggregating the "Image" field inside of it, and that you also have the "Image" field itself set to display. This would account for the same image being displayed twice.

Comment: Thanks! That wasn't quite the answer cause I already did that but you did prompt me in the right direction. There were two pill tabs I didn't notice before in the top right, one for "Default" and one for "Full Content" I didn't edit "Full Content" cause I didn't see it before.

Comment: I'll accept as soon as SE lets me.

Comment: Good stuff, glad to help :)